# Is there a way to toggle a string between single and double quotes in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for an emacs command that will toggle the surrounding quote characters on the string under the point, e.g. with the cursor in the string 'bar', hit a key and change it between:

```
foo = 'bar'   <--->   foo = "bar"
```

For bonus points it would:

- handle toggling Python triple-quote strings (`'''` <---> `"""`)
- automatically change backslash escaping inside the string as appropriate.

e.g.

```
foo = 'bar "quote"'   <--->   foo = "bar \"quote\""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick hack to get you started:

```
(defun toggle-quotes ()
  "Toggle single quoted string to double or vice versa, and
  flip the internal quotes as well.  Best to run on the first
  character of the string."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (re-search-backward "[\"']")
    (let* ((start (point))
           (old-c (char-after start))
           new-c)
      (setq new-c 
            (case old-c
              (?\" "'")
              (?\' "\"")))
      (setq old-c (char-to-string old-c))
      (delete-char 1)
      (insert new-c)
      (re-search-forward old-c)
      (backward-char 1)
      (let ((end (point)))
        (delete-char 1)
        (insert new-c)
        (replace-string new-c old-c nil (1+ start) end)))))
```

The function swaps the internal quotes to the opposite, which is close to bonus 2.

Answer (score 7):

This could be a bit more robust:

```
(defun toggle-quotes ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((start (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)))
          (quote-length 0) sub kind replacement)
      (goto-char start)
      (setq sub (buffer-substring start (progn (forward-sexp) (point)))
            kind (aref sub 0))
      (while (char-equal kind (aref sub 0))
        (setq sub (substring sub 1)
              quote-length (1+ quote-length)))
      (setq sub (substring sub 0 (- (length sub) quote-length)))
      (goto-char start)
      (delete-region start (+ start (* 2 quote-length) (length sub)))
      (setq kind (if (char-equal kind ?\") ?\' ?\"))
      (loop for i from 0
            for c across sub
            for slash = (char-equal c ?\\)
            then (if (and (not slash) (char-equal c ?\\)) t nil) do
            (unless slash
              (when (member c '(?\" ?\'))
                (aset sub i
                      (if (char-equal kind ?\") ?\' ?\")))))
      (setq replacement (make-string quote-length kind))
      (insert replacement sub replacement))))
```

It will use syntax information from the buffer to find the quotes at the beginning of the string (that is given that the strings are quoted), and will also try to flip quotes inside the string, unless they are escaped with backslash - which looks like it could be a common case.

PS. I've just realized you also wanted it to find triple quotes, so her goes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something even more robust, in that it doesn't delete the whole text between the quotes (doing so prevents `save-excursion` from keeping the point where it was, which is a pain).  Also handles (un)backslash-ing nested quotes.

```
(defun toggle-quotes ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((beg (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)))
         (orig-quote (char-after beg))
         (new-quote (case orig-quote
                      (?\' ?\")
                      (?\" ?\'))))
    (save-restriction
     (widen)
     (save-excursion
      (catch 'done
        (unless new-quote
          (message "Not inside a string")
          (throw 'done nil))
        (goto-char beg)
        (delete-char 1)
        (insert-char new-quote)
        (while t
          (cond ((eobp)
                 (throw 'done nil))
                ((= (char-after) orig-quote)
                 (delete-char 1)
                 (insert-char new-quote)
                 (throw 'done nil))
                ((= (char-after) ?\\)
                 (forward-char 1)
                 (when (= (char-after) orig-quote)
                   (delete-char -1))
                 (forward-char 1))
                ((= (char-after) new-quote)
                 (insert-char ?\\)
                 (forward-char 1))
                (t (forward-char 1)))))))))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a function I made for JavaScript, might help?

```js
function swap_str(e, r, t) {
  return e = e.split(r).join("WHAK_a_SWAP"), e = e.split(t).join("WHAK_b_SWAP"), e = e.split("WHAK_a_SWAP").join(t), 
  e = e.split("WHAK_b_SWAP").join(r);
}
//test 1
var str = 'this is "test" of a \'test\' of swapping strings';
var manipulated = swap_str(str,"'",'"');
document.writeln(manipulated)
//test 2
manipulated = swap_str(manipulated,"'",'"');
document.writeln('<hr>'+manipulated)
```